# Правописание проприальных перифраз

Tags: орфография

Вот уже не первый год всевозможные словари и справочники я читаю чаще, чем иные попы «Отче наш», консультирую здесь всех с такой уверенностью в себе, как будто я академик Виноградов, а элементарных вещей не знаю.

Недавно я интересовалась перифразами, заменяющими слово "Россия", в связи с чем у меня возник как раз такой вопрос, для ответа на который требуются элементарные знания. Собственно, когда я задалась этим вопросом, он сводился к тому, выделяется ли прописной буквой первое (или единственное) слово в проприальных перифразах, однако Нацкорпус мне значительно расширил глаза, предложив все возможные варианты вплоть до немыслимых. Так я окончательно убедилась, что я полный патриарх лесов.

Патриарх патриархом, а известные широкой общественности источники информации об орфографических нормах Нацкорпусом, хвала богам, не исчерпываются. Однако справочная литература разъяснениями существующего порядка не изобилует. Остается надеяться на вашу помощь. Не откажете в любезности?

Comment: Не знаю, ошибка ли у автора "Стилистики", - я смотрела диссертации о топонимических перифразах.

Comment: Положим, с топонимическими перифразами разобрались. Но проприальные перифразы оными не исчерпываются — к их числу принадлежат также перифразы имен известных лиц. Из собственных наблюдений я могу сделать вывод, что эти перифразы пишутся со строчной буквы, однако Нацкорпус предлагает начертать перифраз «солнце русской поэзии» и со строчной, и с прописной, и даже в кавычках  — словом, как вашей милости угодно.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, перифразы к слову "Россия" проприальные (именные), а не апеллятивные, потому что относятся к имени собственному, а еще точнее - топонимические. Именные перифразы бывают образные (метафорические и метонимические) и безобразные, окказиональные и узуальные (идентифицирующие объект вне контекста). От этого и зависит их написание.

**Узуальные образные топонимические перифразы**, то есть узнаваемые, практические ставшие вторым официальным названием, пишутся с прописной: *Страна восходящего солнца (о Японии), Страна утренней свежести (о Корее), Поднебесная империя (об императорском Китае), Страна кленового листа (о Канаде), Страна тюльпанов (Голландии), Вечный
город (о Риме), Белокаменная, Первопрестольная (о Москве), Северная Пальмира (о Санкт-Петербурге)*.

**Окказиональные образные топонимические перифразы** пишутся в кавычках со строчной: *Недаром Кузбасс называют «каменным сердцем страны»*. Но возможно и написание без кавычек. Как пишет Грамота.ру, решение о постановке кавычек принимает автор.

**Необразные топонимические перифразы** пишутся без кавычек со строчной: *город на Неве, русская земля*.

Comment: >Насколько я понимаю, перифразы к слову "Россия" проприальные (именные), а не апеллятивные, потому что относятся к имени собственному, а еще точнее - топонимические.

Апеллятив - синоним термина "имя нарицательное", тем не менее автор "Стилистики русского языка и культуры речи" Людмила Богданова перифразы имён собственных называет именно апеллятивными. Ошибка?

Спасибо за разъяснения, @tat.

>Не знаю, ошибка ли у автора "Стилистики", - я смотрела диссертации о топонимических перифразах.

А у Вас адресок этой диссертации... я извиняюсь...